# Passing variables between 2 scripts (gui and main)

Tags: python

I have two scripts, Main1 and gui. I have imported Main1 to my gui.

In Main1, in the class called Search, and I have the function search_gene which obtains a string of information associated with the variable list_of_records. The code for search_gene is below.

```
list_of_records = record["IdList"] 
return list_of_records
```

In the gui, I have a button called Search, which when pressed runs the function search_gene. I have a box that will then display the items in list_of_records after the button is pressed. The code for the list box is below.

```
results_box = ListBox(app, grid=[1,3], items=list_of_records,  width = 260, height=200, scrollbar
```

However, I keep getting this error and I'm not sure what to do:

```
NameError: name 'list_of_records' is not defined
```

Comment: Seems like `list_of_records` isn't in the global scope of Main1. It looks like you just create it in the function `search_gene` and return it if that function is called. So maybe something like `items=search_gene()` would work?

Comment: I just tried this and I got the same error sadly

Comment: Really? The same `list_of_records is not defined` error? Then you must not be saving your code before running it, or there's another reference to `list_of_records` that you didn't show in your example. Or is the error something like `search_gene is not defined`?

Comment: It works now, I just made an error in typing the code out from your suggestion, thank you for the help!

Comment: Cool I'll post it as an answer then so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list_of_records` isn't in the global scope of Main1. It's just created in the function `search_gene` and returned if that function is called. So, the code `items=list_of_records` should be replaced with `items=search_gene()`.